# Cron jobs on RaspBMC

Tags: cron, xbmc

I'm trying to make the following script run at 17:00 everyday on Raspbmc using crontab. Cronjob scheduler is activated and running, but the script does not get executed. The crontab I used is:

`0 17 * * * python /home/pi/.kodi/userdata/test.py`

and my script is:

```
import xbmc
xbmc.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(/home/pi/.kodi/userdata/playlists/music/test.m3u)")
xbmc.executebuiltin("PlayerControl(Random)")
```

I could use a service called "XBMC Alarm clock", it works, but I need the songs to be shuffled!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the full path to python. Use "which python" to get the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to execute the following through SSH:

1).`sudo apt-get install xbmc-eventclients-xbmc-send`

2).`xbmc-send --action='RunScript("/home/pi/.kodi/userdata/test.py")'` (to test if the script works through SSH)

or

3).0 17 * * * xbmc-send --action='RunScript("/home/pi/.kodi/userdata/test.py")' (to set the crontab)

Of course you need to make the script executable (755 permissions) and set the python env, as previously mentioned.

Thanks for the the replies!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Raspbmc but since you are using python:

1. have you made your test.py executable? (eg: 755 permissions on the file)
2. set the python env in test.py

I tend to prefer the second option when working with python files and add at the top of my file something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

R.